# How to make regex that accept single dot or commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I already made regex that prevent 00 at the beginning and accept 0-9, commas, and dot.
But didn't stop double commas or double dot between number.
How to prevent double commas/dot in the input? So only accept single dot and single comma

I want it only accept like 5.50 or 5,20.

if already use dot, don't accept comma, vice versa

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  
  const [lendData, setLendData] = useState({
    lendValue: '',
    lendFee: '',
  })

  function handleChange(e) {
    let { name, value } = e.target
    
    value = value.replace(/^0+|[^0-9,.]|,{2,}/g, '')
    
    setLendData((prev) => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          [name]: value,
        }
      })
      
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

 <input
          type='text'
          inputMode='decimal'
          name='fee'
          id='fee'
          placeholder='0%'
          value={lendData.lendFee}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
```

This is what I did so far with regex

```
/^0+|[^0-9,.]|,{2,}/g
```

[image]

Comment: You are replacing 2 or or more comma's with this `,{2,}` with an empty string, you could replace 2 or more comma's / dots with a single one.

Comment: The `[^0-9,.]` sequence in the middle of your pattern will allow it to match almost every character, as well as every zero-length point between characters. Also, do you only want to match numbers that represent floating point values, or are multi-part numbers with more than one dot/comma (e.g. "5.0.1") also valid as long as the dots/commas don't appear next to each other?

Comment: I just want to match 1 floating number only either using comas or dot. If you put 1,1 don't allow it to put 1,1,1,1, it should be accept 1,1111. The same rules for dot. If already put a coma, don't allowed to put a dot, vice versa. Also don't accept coma/dot in sequence like 1,,111 or 1..000

Comment: Is your goal to correct invalid input, (e.g. change ",1..2," to ",1.2,"), erase invalid input (e.g. change ",1..2," to ","), or to extract and process valid input?

Comment: @phatfingers my goal is to correct the invalid input

Comment: How would you treat something like "1.2.3.4"?

Comment: I was thinking to make it only allowed single dot/coma sir

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead assertion in regex as this will ensure that the input does not contain consecutive occurrences of dot or comma.

```
/^0+|[^0-9,.]|(?<=\d)[.,](?!\d)|,[,.]|,{2,}/g
```

Comment: this regex have to put all the numbers first before giving coma or dot. Which is inefficient if someone want to type 5,5. User needs to type 55 first, and then giving a coma/dot

Answer (score 0):

You could use replace with a callback, where you remove the leading zeroes, replace 2 or more dots or comma's with a single one, and according to the first detected dot or zero remove the other ones different from the first detected one.

The regex has 3 capture groups, where you would return a concatenation of group 1, group 2 and the removed characters other than the initial detected comma or dot.

```
^([^.,\n]*)([.,])(.*)
```

The regex matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([^.,\n]*)` Capture group 1, match optional repetition of any char except `.` `,` or a newline
- `([.,])` Group 2, match either `.` or `,`
- `(.*)` Group 3, match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oHMeUN/1)

```js
function handleChange() {
  const regex = /^([^.,\n]*)([.,])(.*)/;

  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/^0+/g, '')         // remove leading zeroes
    .replace(/([.,])\1+/g, "$1") // replace multiple dots or comma's with a single one

  this.value = this.value.replace(regex, (_, g1, g2, g3) =>
    g1 + g2 + g3.replace(g2 === "." ? /,/g : /\./g, "")
  );
}

const fee = document.getElementById("fee");

if (fee) {
  fee.addEventListener("input", handleChange);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fee" />
```